# What is the way in cygwin to install everything from a local directory from the command line

Tags: installation, command-line, cygwin

I have a local repo of cygwin that I would like to deploy across various test machines.  Is there a command that I could script out to install cygwin along with all of the packages in my local repository?

Answer (score 0):

You may notice that, in the Category view, all categories are children of the "super-category" `All`, so `setup -L -C All` should get you started.